# Best way to handle special events at the end of each month in a time series

Tags: time-series, forecasting, anomaly-detection

I am currently working with grouped time series where I have data disaggregated on a daily basis.
I use Facebook Prophet and the results are in general okay with one small catch.
There is one aspect that I am not sure how to take into consideration. Due to the nature of how data is logged (essentially, this is explained by how the billing system works), there are some extremely high values on each 28th day of a month and then a dramatic drop in the next several days.
While this rule works for most months, sometimes it breaks and there are no anomalies.

I am wondering what is the best way to take account of this factor. One idea was to enable monthly seasonality in Facebook Prophet, but then I read an article by professor Hyndman where the recommendation is to add a custom regressor.

I tried this approach, but it seems that nothing changed and the model wasn't able to adapt to the strange trend.

Another idea is to use a completely different approach to the problem and try gradient boosting so that the timestamp is split into many theoretically useful features like `year, month, day_of_month, day_of_year, end_of_month`, etc.  It seems, however, that there is just too little data (overall, around 900 rows) and the model tends to overfit and is thus not likely to be useful.

Is there anything worth trying in this case? Thanks!

Comment: how did you add a a custom regression, and how did it not work?

Comment: just ignore/drop the data on the problematic days is the easiest

Comment: if you know which day(s) the problem may appear, then having a categorical variable to represent it, is_end_of_month, should make it possible to learn this behaviour